# Is it possbile to use Drupal Views to relate Webform Submissions and CiviCRM Contacts and Cases?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-views

We use Drupal (7) Webforms integrated with CiviCRM for various use cases, particularly recruitment forms.

I can create a Drupal View of *either* Webform Submissions OR CiviCRM Cases, but I cannot combine the two as there is no obvious way of relating a Webform submission to the CiviCRM contact that submitted it unless they are a Drupal User  - the vast majority of submissions are not for us.

I can see a Drupal database table called `webform_civicrm_submissions` but this is not your usual SQL table that can be accessed via Views it seems.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest answer I can give is, no.

I can't think of a way of combining civi information and webform submission details.

What you can do is the use relationships in Civi to start with case data, and then bring into the view other data in civicrm linked to the case.
The case contact for example
And also data about any case activities

What data from the webform submission are you wanting to show alongside the Civi Contact/ Case Data?

Are you able to give an example?

Answer (score 0):

there may be a gotcha but if you start a View based on webform submissions then you can join (via Relationships) the Drupal user, then you can get to the Contact, and in theory you would then be able to get to the Case.

my quick example didn't work but maybe doing so in reverse

Comment: Thanks Peter - This comment will answer Craig's comment below as well. The issue is that as I mentioned, there is no Drupal User.  When someone applies for a role at the charity, we anonymise the details in various ways.  We create a Case from an anonymous Drupal user submitting a Webform.  One of the things I wanted to display was an exact time of submission, which I can get from the Webform submission, but the Case Created date has no time.  We could force people to register as a Drupal User, but it seems wasteful given that there is ultimately a link between the submission and the case.

Comment: sorry missed that point. surprised there is nothing from Case that gives you exact time but if so why not add a different Activity on to the webform, as well as the Case, and that presumably would get the exact time

Comment: Yes, either an Activity or a custom field is the probably the way forward.  If you do know of a (Views accessible) Case field, let me know! Thanks for the input as always.